# Uneven grid with for loop(s)

Tags: c#, for-loop, xna-4.0

So here is my problem:

I have an RPG inventory that draws items in a grid(7x4), via two for loops:

```
[Update Method]

index = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < ItemList.Count / 7; y++)
    {
        ItemList[index].gridLocation = new Point(x, y);
        index++;
    }
}
```

*ItemList is just a list of the BaseItem class.

This is how I would want this code to draw the grid:

```
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X
```

But this is how it does it instead:

```
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X
```

It cuts off the end row that isn't greater than or equal to 7.

Now when I use an item(using an item removes it from the list), it adds the next hidden item to the end of the 3rd row.

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks,

EDIT: Thanks to Nico for the help, this is what my code looks like now:

```
                if (ItemList.Count > 6)
                {
                    for (int index = 0; index < ItemList.Count; ++index)
                    {
                        ItemList[index].gridLocation = new Point(index % 7, (int)(index / 7));
                        ItemList[index].UpdateValues(ScreenLocation, itemSize, LocY);
                    }
                }
                else if (ItemList.Count < 7)
                {
                    for (int index = 0; index < ItemList.Count; ++index)
                    {
                        ItemList[index].gridLocation = new Point(index, 0);
                        ItemList[index].UpdateValues(ScreenLocation, itemSize, LocY);
                    }
                }
```

I found there was a problem where if the itemList was below 7, it wouldn't display any of the items. Above code fixes it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate using the index:

```
for(int index = 0; index < ItemList.Count; ++index)
    ItemList[index].gridLocation = new Point(index % 7, (int)(index / 7));
```

Note that I have flipped the item order. Yours was column-wise, now it is row-wise. I assume, you meant this, because you have a fixed grid width of 7 and a variable row number. If that's not correct, leave a comment.

Comment: First thank you for the fast reply, and second, it worked instantly. Thank you so much! This problem has been in my code for quite a bit.